# How can I bring down an evil website to prevent it from warping reality?

Tags: society, alternate-reality, internet

In Wisconsin 2014, two 12 year old girls were accused of stabbing another playmate 19 times. When questioned by authorities, they admitted to committing the attempted murder in order to demonstrate their loyalty to Slenderman. This mythical creature of folklore is known for either manipulating children to do terrible things, or simply kidnapping them from their homes and eating them. People pass this off as an urban legend and superstitious nonsense, but the reality is that monsters like this exist. Even more horrifying, they can all be traced back to one specific location: CreepyPasta.

CreepyPasta is the most deadly and insidious phenomenon to hit the internet. It's website is devoted to users creating horror related stories meant to scare readers. These stories spread like memes to other parts of the web, increasing awareness of the monsters. This includes those who have never visited the site, turning the story into an urban legend. As stories become popular and more well known,  the paranormal properties of the site activate. Reality alters itself around it's legend, creating a new history. Due to this, the creatures or situations of the material (The Russian experiment, the scp foundation, reddit.com, etc) are being written into the world timeline. The most monstrous and terrifying abominations are coming to life and making the world more dangerous.

Despite all of the increasing paranormal dangers being traced back to one place, nobody seems to make the connection. For regular people, history has always been this way for them, or it is written off as superstitious crap made up on the internet. As history is being altered by users imaginations, it becomes difficult to get proof and link  these two connections together. How would I be able to do this?

Comment: Isn't this a plot question? (How can my detective identify and prove a supernatural link between the Internet and recent phenomena?) Alternatively, it could be opinion-based as devising a magic system for you. (What is the link between the Internet and recent supernatural phenomena?)

Comment: As-written, you're asking us to write your story for you. Please identify the rules or systems of your world that we're working with. In other words, you explain (as @Frostfyre points out) your magic system to us and we can help you determine how a non-user/non-believer could detect its use. But at the moment, you haven't explained your magic system and we have nothing to work with.

Comment: If the site brings fiction into reality, that means Dr.Bright and Site-13 can come into existence. In that case, you don't need evidence, just Jesus because you're going to have a super bad time.

Comment: What's your definition of "bringing down"? Finding a proof and making authorities bring it down? Hack it and bring it down? Arm yourself with silver bullets and bring down the ones who are running it?

Comment: There were nutters and fools before the internet. Nutters find a way. Fools ignore the signs.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't under normal circumstances. What you can do is use the site to fight back.**

As far as the question is structured, it seems like there's only a single person which is somehow either allowed by the site to be aware of its properties or is simply immune to the site's bending on human perception regarding the existence of the entities it spawns into our world (I'll call this person 00). Like you said, the site warps reality itself, making it so not only that creepypastas become real, but also that no one is even slightly capable of suspecting its participation, as if these things have always existed (I'm assuming the entries brought to reality remain in the site). That means that no matter what 00 does,it's not possible to convince someone that the site is paranormal, because even if 00 manages to write an entry popular enough to trigger the website's effects, reality will be rewritten and 00 will look like an idiot, just like all the others who apparently used the site to write about something real instead of making a creepypasta. I also doubt this site wants to be destroyed, after all what's it doing wrong, but bringing people's fantasies to life? In this case, the very fact only popular enough stories are brought to life already acts as a defense mechanism, meaning that simply writing a story in which the site ceases to exist or is found out isn't enough to end it, it requires popularity.

Given this, it seems that the only way to stop the website from causing further damage is by using the site itself,which means we'll need a campaign to popularize a creepypasta about the site itself. As ending the site is too boring for anything other than a movie or book, the best and easiest course of action seems to be 00 writing a story about gaining control over the site and it's reality bending capabilities. Once it's written, 00 will need help "advertising" it, be it by making a video about it on YouTube, posting pictures online which indicate for the story being "real" like we saw with slenderman or by other means. Checking for historical myths to base the story on will make it easier to make it more believable within the limits of a creepypasta. In case of success, the site will make the story real, and 00 will have absolute control over the entirety of the website, including deciding whether new entries can be added or whether an entry will or not become or remain part of the real world, as well as the ability to delete the site itself. It should be noted however that even then the paranormal site might try to keep itself alive and running in some way or another .

Just remember: this is a site for creepypastas, so writing a story with a true happy ending for everyone in which you fix the world might not work. Besides, now 00 has control over a site that can make fantasies come to life, so doesn't getting rid of it sounds like a waste? Is it truly fair to destroy everyone's effort in the fantasies they wrote about? Is 00 truly sure that getting rid of something that could potentially solve all problems, so long as they're written correctly? Those doubts might come up, but it should be easy to shake them off, maybe.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph, was thinking about power making you malevolent, Portal 2 style